# Delete data from table efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, oracle11g

We are using a tool in which we need to delete log tables.Right now,we are keeping 1 million rows and deleting rest of rows if any.This is time consuming and sometimes in production takes 12 hours to delete the data,which affects daily transactions.Is there any other way to delete log tables efficiently,without affecting daily transactions.

Lets suppose we want to keep 1 million rows:

```
Select query:

Select Query:select min(date) from (select date from table order by date desc) where rownum <= 1000000

Delete Query:

Delete Query:Delete from table where date > (result of select query)
```

Is there any way we can optimize these two queries?

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? The details will vary but have you tried deleting in batches instead of the whole set?

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle? You have both tagged.

Comment: Its for both mssql and oracle

Comment: I haven't tried to delete in batches,will it be beneficial?

Comment: you could try making a copy table, doing the deletes on that, and then renaming the tables when done; of course you'd have to also insert any rows augmented after the copy ....

Comment: yes, deleting in batches is beneficial, and sometimes even needed (or else it will timeout due to logging problems with the db itself)

Comment: what would happen on present transactions during copying?

Comment: [Aaron Bertrand has a good post about this for SQL Server](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes)

Comment: Of course it could be helpful. But we don't really know how much data you are deleting. You said all but 1 million rows. How many rows are there? Maybe it is the query that is determining which rows to keep that is the performance bottleneck. The best anybody can do at this point is guess wildly.

Comment: Total,there may be 10-15 million rows.There is query which will keep 1 million rows sorted by date and delete rest of rows.

Comment: Right but what is that query? It could be that query that is the problem, not the delete itself. Although I suspect if you are deleting 10-15 million rows that is going to be an issue. But again, the query that find those rows can also be a major performance problem.

Comment: @mahan07 how often are you running this process to purge those records?

Comment: @mahan07 A post that might help you. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/painless-management-of-a-logging-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean-We are running once in every week.

Comment: @SeanLange-I have updated query in question.

Answer (score 3):

Inserts into a smaller table are much faster than deletions from a larger table. In this case you can insert the records you want to keep into a staging table. **If logging is not a concern** and **referential integrity will allow it**, you could simply:

1. Create a staging table that is an exact copy of your log table.
2. Insert the records you intend to keep from your log table into your staging table.
3. Drop your log table.
4. Rename your staging table to log.

Comment: Where will the present records stored?

Comment: @mahan07 - The source table is the log table with the millions of rows to be deleted. Just insert the rows you do not want to deleted into a separate physical table, if allowable. It will be much, much faster.

Comment: Is this really an option? If they have that many records daily, they would constantly be inserting into it. I can't imagine this process wouldn't cause blocking/errors

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - I would  not want to do this everyday and I did not see where it was said to be a daily process. It was mentioned that when done it affected daily tx's (dropping and renaming a table is a meta change taking only seconds). Other than a partition based scheme, this would be the fastest approach, however, you are correct if this is going to be done daily then it may not be ideal.

Comment: @RossBush-Every seconds we are having a transaction.Where i can keep all those logs when I am dropping log table?This process will have downtime.

Comment: @mahan07 - If you can not include this in a planned downtime when the table can go offline for a few seconds then this solution is not for you. Do you know the condition that makes the log record included to be deleted prior to inserting?

Comment: Didnt get your question.

Comment: @mahan07 - Sorry if the question was unclear. I was asking if you could split the incoming data into two tables, one for short retention and one for longer retention?

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete ten thousand rows at a time.

```
delete top (10000) from tableA where condition1 <> xyz
while (@@rowcount >0)
begin
     delete top (10000) from tableA where condition1 <> xyz

end
delete from tablea where condition1 <> xyz
```

This way you wont have a large transaction log. You may want to experiment with the number of rows (some people go with 1000 rows) but its very dependent on the amount of activity in your machine and the speed of your drives and the placement and configuration of your log files. You said you want to keep certain rows so I added condition1 <> xyz